# locked update button at the moment to update one row

Tags: jquery, datatables

At the moment when I want to update my prouct. my button it's locked I dont know why it happends that, I tried to rewrite the function , but it didnt work .
once the item is updated it should   `$('#update_product')[0].reset(); table.ajax.reload();` refresh the table and reset the form. however it doesnt. how can I fix it?

```
  $('#example tbody').on('click','a', function(e){
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr')).data();
       hash_id = data[0];
       $("#update_product").validate();
       BootstrapDialog.show({
            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
            message: function(dialog) {
                var $message = $('<div></div>');
                var pageToLoad = dialog.getData('pageToLoad');
                $message.load(pageToLoad);

                return $message;
            },
            data: {
                'pageToLoad': URL_GET_VIEW_UPDATE_PRODUCT
            },
            closable: false,
                        buttons:[{
                id: 'btn-ok',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-send',
                label: ' Save',
                action: function (e) {
                    var hash = hash_id;
                    var description = $('#description').val();
                    var cost_price = $('#cost_price').val();
                    var selling_price = $('#selling_price').val();
                    var wprice = $('#wprice').val();
                    var min_stock = $('#min_stock').val();
                    var stock = $('#stock').val();
                    var max_stock = $('#max_stock').val();
                    if($("#update_product").valid()){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: URL_GET_UPDATE_PRODUCT_PRODUCT,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {hash: hash, description: description, cost_price: cost_price, selling_price: selling_price, wprice: wprice, min_stock: min_stock, stock: stock, max_stock: max_stock}
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            if (data.msg == 'successfully updated') {
                                $('#update_product')[0].reset();
                                table.ajax.reload();
                            }else if(data.min_stock == 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min'){
                                BootstrapDialog.show({
                                    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
                                    message: 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min'
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            },{
                id: 'btn-cancel',
                cssClass: 'btn-danger',
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                label: ' Cancel',
                action: function (e) {
                    e.close();
                }
            }]

        });
    });
```

html

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="bootstrap-dialog-header">
            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-close-button" style="display: none;">
                <button class="close">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-title" id="40c4c7e9-f969-496f-b032-f8087c34df21_title">Warning</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="bootstrap-dialog-body">
            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-message">
                <div>
                    <form id="update_product">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Name: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" title="product description" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-inline">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label for="cost_price">Cost Price: </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cost_price" name="cost_price" title="cost_price" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label for="selling_price">Selling price: </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="selling_price" name="selling_price" title="selling_price" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-inline">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label for="wprice">Wholeprice: </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="wprice" name="wprice" title="wprice" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label for="min_stock">Min stock: </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="min_stock" name="min_stock" title="min_stock" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label for="stock">Stock: </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock" name="stock" title="stock" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label for="max_stock">Max stock: </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="max_stock" name="max_stock" title="max_stock" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="display: block;">
        <div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer">
            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-ok"><span class="bootstrap-dialog-button-icon glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-cancel"><span class="bootstrap-dialog-button-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[locked button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpeD6.png)
[refreshed page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZWLW.png)

Comment: is that modal always in the DOM or is it been added dynamically? Most likely the event is been bond when the element is not present and the binding doesn't actually happen. here is some documentation on [Event deligation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: it didnt work with event.preventDefault();

Comment: try to do a console log whenever they are clicked. try to simplify the button event as much as possible and then little by little add the events back to figure out what's blocking the action. [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) keyword is very helpful it will freeze the JS to inspect what's happening and where

Comment: still no working